# JAX RS API to invoke Selenium functions

Tags: java, selenium, jax-rs

I am trying to write an API that invokes certain Selenium functions. My class that handles these selenium functions executes by itself but gives the following error when called through the API

This is the stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:421)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:483)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:313)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    com.ahuja.jersey.first.Hello.sayPlainTextHello(Hello.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    com.ahuja.jersey.first.Hello.sayPlainTextHello(Hello.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:164)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Update : When I check the build path of the project, I can see the Selenium JAR files. But still get the same error.

Comment: Looks like you don't have WebDriver in your ClassPath

Comment: When I check the projects build path I can see the selenium JAR files. but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually add the JAR files in the lib folder within the workspace